# How do I properly override __setattr__ and __getattribute__ on new-style classes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, python-2.x, setattr

I want to override my Python class's `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` methods. My use case is the usual one: I have a few special names that I want to handle, and I want the default behavior for anything else. For `__getattribute__`, it seems that I can request the default behavior simply by raising `AttributeError`. However, how can I achieve the same in `__setattr__`? Here is a trivial example, implementing a class with immutable fields "A", "B", and "C".

```
class ABCImmutable(SomeSuperclass):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in ("A", "B", "C"):
            return "Immutable value of %s" % name
        else:
            # This should trigger the default behavior for any other
            # attribute name.
            raise AttributeError()

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in ("A", "B", "C"):
            raise AttributeError("%s is an immutable attribute.")
        else:
            # How do I request the default behavior?
            ???
```

What goes in place of the question marks? With old-style classes, the answer was apparently `self.__dict__[name] = value`, but documentation indicates that this is wrong for new-style classes.

Comment: "documentation indicates that this is wrong for new-style classes"...and didn't it indicate what was right for new-style classes?

Comment: Why aren't you just implementing your named fields as set-only properties?

Comment: The immutability was just a trivial example use case for __setattr__. My actual use is a bit more complicated. My class inherits from dict, but in addition, certain special keys (determined at runtime) are accessible `object.key` instead of `object['key']`. I could probably add them as properties using runtime reflection or something, but it's easier to use `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`, and performance isn't particularly critical.

Comment: By the way the reason why self.__dict__[name] = value wouldn't work is because you need to get the attribute self.__dict__ to do this, and thus cause infinite recursions.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's

```
super(ABCImmutable, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```

in Python 2, or

```
super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

in Python 3.

Also, raising `AttributeError` is **not** how you fall back to the default behavior for `__getattribute__`. You fall back to the default with

```
return super(ABCImmutable, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

on Python 2 or

```
return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

on Python 3.

Raising `AttributeError` skips the default handling and goes to `__getattr__`, or just produces an `AttributeError` in the calling code if there's no `__getattr__`.

See the documentation on [Customizing Attribute Access](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access).

Comment: Close, but you don't need the second "self".  You'd call it like this:

    super(ABCImmutable, self).__setattr__(name, value)

Otherwise you'll get the "expected 2 arguments, but got three" exception.

Answer (score 6):

`SomeSuperclass.__setattr__(self, name, value)` ?

Comment: Don't I need a call to `super` somewhere? At least in the general case?

Comment: @Ryan Thompson I'm pretty sure you can use `super()` in place of `SomeSuperclass` but I'm trying to track down whether that is specific to Python 3.

Comment: @Ryan Thompson Looking at the [Python 2 examples for Raymond Hettinger's "Python's super() considered super!" post](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577721-how-to-use-super-effectively-python-27-version/), it looks like it would be `super(ABCImmutable, self).__setattr__(self, name, value)` in Python 2. I'll update my answer with what I think should be the correct invocation.

Comment: you can also use super: `super(ABCImmutable, self).__setattr__(name, value)` in python 2.x or `super().__setattr__(name, value)` in 3.x. Maybe you want to have a look at this: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: This answer most closely follows the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access). The techniques (`SomeSuperClass...` or `super...`) seem equivalent to me, but if you use `super` do take note of the args passed in as shown by @Jeannot and @Dave's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042152/how-do-i-properly-override-setattr-and-getattribute-on-new-style-classes#comment9675936_7042247).

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to do the trick:

```py
class ABCImmutable:
    def __getattribute__(self, name:str):
        if name in ("A", "B", "C"):
            return "Immutable value of %s" % name
        else:
            return super(ABCImmutable, self).__getattribute__(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name:str, value):
        if name in ("A", "B", "C"):
            msg = "%s is an immutable attribute." % name
            # msg = f"{name} is an immutable attribute."
            # msg = "{} is an immutable attribute.".format(name)
            raise AttributeError(msg)
        else:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
```