# How to change setter and getter for self to be able to work on class and composition in python

Tags: python, getter-setter

I am trying to change **setattr** and **getattr** methods in my class, but i have got an error when i am trying to define both of them.

```
class Basee:
def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app
    self.x = 3

def test(self):
    return self.x

def __getattr__(self, item):
    if item in dir(self):
        return getattr(self, item)
    elif item in dir(self.app):
        return getattr(self.app, item)
    else:
        if item in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[item]
        else:
            return self.app.__dict__[item]

class App:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
    def test2(self):
        return self.y

app = App(5)
test = Basee(app)
```

Above code with only **getattr** works fine.

```
class Basee:
def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app
    self.x = 3

def test(self):
    return self.x

def __getattr__(self, item):
    if item in dir(self):
        return getattr(self, item)
    elif item in dir(self.app):
        return getattr(self.app, item)
    else:
        if item in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[item]
        else:
            return self.app.__dict__[item]

def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    if key in self.__dict__:
        return self.__setattr__(key, value)
    else:
        return self.app.__setattr__(key, value)

class App:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
    def test2(self):
        return self.y

app = App(5)
test = Basee(app)
```

Above code with both methods raise and error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in 
run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-41-5e27f0c3b3cf>", line 8, in <module>
    test = Basee(app)
  File "<ipython-input-40-eff8d695cb0e>", line 3, in __init__
    self.app = app
  File "<ipython-input-40-eff8d695cb0e>", line 24, in __setattr__
    return self.app.__setattr__(key, value)
  File "<ipython-input-40-eff8d695cb0e>", line 12, in __getattr__
    elif item in dir(self.app):
  File "<ipython-input-40-eff8d695cb0e>", line 12, in __getattr__
    elif item in dir(self.app):
  File "<ipython-input-40-eff8d695cb0e>", line 12, in __getattr__
    elif item in dir(self.app):
  [Previous line repeated 1486 more times]
  File "<ipython-input-40-eff8d695cb0e>", line 10, in __getattr__
    if item in dir(self):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

How can I repair it? 
I want to get and set all methods and atribitues of Base and App class by refereing to Base class, for example writing:
test.y =7 should change in the code backgorund self.app.y on 7 
then when I try to get test.y i can see 7 and it refer to self.app.y :-)
Any ideas?

Comment: I guess this is similar with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042152/how-do-i-properly-override-setattr-and-getattribute-on-new-style-classes

Comment: Unfortunately it's not :/