# How to make immutable attributes in class?

Tags: python, oop

**Problem:** I'm creating a class with attributes. Some of them should be only readable and some should be completely inaccessible when trying to print them out. I'm trying to achieve it through `__setattribute__` and `__getattribute__` functions (I just couldn't think of a better way to do that, if you have any suggestions on how to improve this, I would greatly appreciate it). The problem is that while `__getattribute__` function works perfectly fine and raises needed exception, the `__setattribute__` doesn't. The program simply passes it.

**Code:**

```py
class Fruit:
  def __setattribute__(self, name, value):
    if name in ('exp_date'):
      raise AttributeError('Unable to edit')
    return __setattribute__(self, name, value)
  def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in ('subtype'):
            raise AttributeError('Unable to view this object')
        return __getattribute__(self, name)
  def __init__(self, sub:str = None, col:str = None, expd:int = None, pkp:int = None, amount:int = None):
    self.color, self.price_per_kilo = col, pkp
    self.amount = amount
    self.exp_date = expd
    self.subtype = sub
  def estimaterevenue(self):
    return self.price_per_kilo * self.amount
```

**Test:**

```py
fruit= Fruit()
fruit.exp_date = 123 # __set__ is being passed for some reason
print(fruit.subtype) # AttributeError: Unable to view this object
```

Comment: `fruit.exp_date = 123` would call `__setattribute__` not `__set__`

Comment: @rdas Sorry, wrong version, I've made edits to the post

Comment: Isn't your answer here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042152/how-do-i-properly-override-setattr-and-getattribute-on-new-style-classes

Comment: `('exp_date')` isn't a tuple, by the way. It's just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion about which dunder methods are defined. I don't know either, but I think this does what you want:

```py
class Fruit:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print('set attribute', name)
        if name in ('exp_date'):
            raise AttributeError('Unable to edit')
        return super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

**Update:**

The above code does not work because `exp_date` cannot be set inside `__init__()`.

This code works around that:

```py
class Fruit:
  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    #print('set attribute', name)
    if name in 'attr_gate' or self.attr_gate or name not in 'exp_date':
        return super().__setattr__(name, value)
    raise AttributeError('Unable to edit')
  def __getattribute__(self, name):
        #print('get attribute', name)
        if name in ('subtype'):
            raise AttributeError('Unable to view this object')
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
  def __init__(self, sub:str = None, col:str = None, expd:int = None, pkp:int = None, amount:int = None):
    self.attr_gate = True
    self.color, self.price_per_kilo = col, pkp
    self.amount = amount
    self.exp_date = expd
    self.subtype = sub
    self.attr_gate = False
```

Comment: Wont this give an issue when trying to set attribute in constructor?

Answer (score 2):

`__get_attribute__` and `__set_attr_` are complicated to understand, better use a simple propert:

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, subtype=None, color=None, exp_date=None, price_per_kilo=None, amount=None):
        self.color = color
        self.price_per_kilo = price_per_kilo
        self.amount = amount
        self._exp_date = exp_date
        self._subtype = subtype

    def estimaterevenue(self):
        return self.price_per_kilo * self.amount

    @property
    def exp_date(self):
        return self._exp_date
    

fruit= Fruit()
fruit.exp_date = 123 # AttributeError 
print(fruit.subtype) # AttributeError: Unable to view this object
```

Comment: yeah but he can still do `fruit._subtype`

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation uses a counter so you can set the value once in the constructor but not subsequently.

```
class Fruit: 
  def __setattr__(self, name, value): 
    if name in ('exp_date') and self.count_exp_date>=1: 
      raise AttributeError('Unable to edit') 
    # return __setattribute__(self, name, value) 
    if name in ('exp_date'): 
        self.count_exp_date+=1 
    super().__setattr__(name, value)  
  def __getattribute__(self, name): 
        if name in ('subtype'): 
            raise AttributeError('Unable to view this object') 
        return super().__getattribute__(name) 
  def __init__(self, sub:str = None, col:str = None, expd:int = None, pkp:int = None, amount:int = None): 
    self.count_exp_date = 0 
    self.color, self.price_per_kilo = col, pkp 
    self.amount = amount 
    self.exp_date = expd 
    self.subtype = sub 
  def estimaterevenue(self): 
    return self.price_per_kilo * self.amount
```